# C# How to fix these error (System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Image.get returned null error) and Validate if picturebox is null/empty

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

Below these is the code for saving the image to database. What i want to get help with is to fix these error of mine and validate it if user doesn't choose image it will show a messagebox.

In this picture when i tried to add these informations to my database without choosing the image to my computer file it show these error (System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Image.get returned null error)[image]
This error what i'm talking about[image]

```
public partial class ADDProduct : MetroForm
{
    SIMSProduct _view;
    public ADDProduct(SIMSProduct view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _view = view;       
    }
     private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
            {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbox_supplier.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_code.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_item.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_quantity.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_cost.Text))
            {
                CustomNotifcation.Show("Please input the required fields", CustomNotifcation.AlertType.warning);
            }
            else
            {          
                ValidateCode.IsValidCode(txt_code,lbl_code,ds);
                if (lbl_code.Visible == true)
                {
                    CustomNotifcation.Show("CODE ALREADY EXIST", CustomNotifcation.AlertType.error);
                    lbl_code.Visible = false;

                }
                else
                {
                        using (var select = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee_product (Image, Supplier, Codeitem, Itemdescription, Date, Quantity, Unitcost) Values (@Image, @Supplier, @Codeitem, @Itemdescription, @Date, @Quantity, @Unitcost)", con))
                        {                               
                            var ms = new MemoryStream();
                            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                            var PhotoByte = ms.GetBuffer();                           
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = PhotoByte;
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Supplier", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbox_supplier.Text;
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Codeitem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_code.Text.Trim();
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Itemdescription", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_item.Text.Trim();
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date;
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_quantity.Text.Trim();
                            select.Parameters.Add("@Unitcost", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_cost.Text.Trim();
                            select.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            CustomMessage.Show("Message: Item successfully added!",CustomMessage.Messagetype.Success);
                            pictureBox1.Image = null;
                            cbox_supplier.Items.Clear();
                            txt_code.Clear();
                            txt_item.Clear();
                            txt_quantity.Clear();
                            txt_cost.Clear();
                            _view.btn_update.Enabled = false;
                            _view.AddingProduct();
                        }
                    }                
                }                
            }
    }
  private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var opnfd    = new OpenFileDialog();
        opnfd.Filter            = "Image Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;.*.png;)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;.*.png;";
        opnfd.Title             = "Select Item";

        if (opnfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode    = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Image       = Image.FromFile(opnfd.FileName);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Edited Done, It Doesn't Address my problem

Comment: A rather nice-looking WinForms app by the way.  Well done!

Comment: Can you check if any of `pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat` is `null` in your call to `Image.Save()`?

Comment: Solved it Thanks :) , I just check if Picturebox has image or not

Comment: Great to hear!  Wishing you well